# .auth().verifyIdToken error: Firebase ID token has incorrect algorithm. Expected "none" but got "RS256"

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Solved this problem by using: "firebase serve --only hosting,functions"
verifyIdToken with production Auth is working as expected

---

I am building a SPA with firebase and using Express.js for user validation & routing in my backend.

In my login script I use firebase-u-auth for Google Sign In, then if user logged in

```
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth(app).setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
.then(() => {
  firebase.auth(app).onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
   if (!user)
     return;
   redirectSuccesful(user);
  });
});

  function redirectSuccesful(user) {
    // for development purposes, enable insecure cookies for http on local server
    let secure = window.location.protocol.toLowerCase() === 'https:' || (window.location.hostname !== 'localhost' && window.location.hostname !== '127.0.0.1' && window.location.hostname !== '0.0.0.0');
    user.getIdToken().then((token) => {
      let expDate = expiryDateFromJwt(token);
      let cookies = `__session=${token}; samesite=strict; path=/${expDate ? '; expires=' + expDate.toUTCString() : ''}${secure ? '; secure' : ''}`;
      document.cookie = cookies;
      window.location.assign('/');
    });
  }
```

In my functions folder I use express with

```
const serviceAccount = require('...json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "<my-url>"
});

expressApp.get('/', wrap (async function(req, res){
 const token = getSessionToken(req); //custom function that gets clean saved token from session
 if(token){
   const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
   ...
 }
}))
```

Token seems correct if I pass it in https://jwt.io/, however the function verifyIdToken(token) shows "Firebase ID token has incorrect algorithm. Expected "none" but got "RS256. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token."

Where does the error comes from? Admin config?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the error locally (emulator)? or in production (deployed)?

Comment: This happens when you run the Admin SDK with the emulator, but given an actual ID token. When running with the emulator, the Admin SDK will only verify ID tokens issued by the emulator.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Jayathilaka: true, I am running this in emulator. Thanks for this information! Now it's clear why this error comes up. But couldn't I force somehow the emulator to do auth against the production? Cause I init my app against the production environment? Thanks guys!

Comment: There's no way to do that as far as I know. When you're running the Admin SDK with the emulator, it is assumed that any related client-side components are also running with the emulator. You can submit any specific feedback you have on this behavior at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka "firebase serve --only hosting,functions" solved my problem, it uses production auth server but local hosting & functions

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the authentication to work with the emulator:

[Connect your app to the Authentication Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#web)

```js
import auth = firebase.auth;
import FirebaseUser = firebase.User;

if (!environment.production) {
  firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');
}
```